# Sqlite3 cursor method in python for inserting for fresh and updating for duplicate keys

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

MySQL has something like this:

```
INSERT INTO visits (ip, hits)
VALUES ('127.0.0.1', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = hits + 1;
```

The method to implement this in Sqlite3 was given which I am reproducing below:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO visits VALUES ($ip, 0);
UPDATE visits SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE ip LIKE $ip;
```

Now I need to implement the same in Python with the cursor method. But I don't know how to put in the string equivalent to the above queries. please be noted that 'ip' and 'hits' are variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just call [execute()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) with the SQL statement:

```
ip = '127.0.0.1'
cursor.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO visits VALUES ($ip, 0);', [ip])
cursor.execute('UPDATE visits SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE ip = $ip;', [ip])
```

Comment: The placeholder needs to be `?` in this case.

Comment: @JonClements No, SQLite [supports $ just fine](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam).

Comment: Nope - I stand corrected - thanks. Somehow having a named placeholder and not using a mapping type as the values just doesn't feel right to me, but it does seem to take them in order of the names listed and not worry about it... (`'insert into whatever (x, y) values ($x, $y)', [y, x]` for instance)